# AWS Codepipeline Events not being caught Rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I am fairly new to AWS but I have a decent understanding of what I want and what should happen. I am playing around with creating CI/CD from CDK and I created a simple three-stage process.

1. I get the source from the Github
2. I build the code
3. I deploy the build artifacts to S3

This successful deploy triggers a lambda that copies over the static html into a new bucket used to host a static website.

But for some reason, the rule I setup to trigger the Lambda is never triggered. (I tested the lambda manually and it works as expected). For debugging purposes I also added an email notification when deploy succeeds but it also never is sent (I confirmed my email).

Pipeline stack

```js
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import * as codebuild from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-codebuild";
import * as lambda from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda";
import * as codepipeline from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-codepipeline";
import * as cpactions from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-codepipeline-actions";
import * as s3 from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-s3";
import * as sns from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-sns';
import * as snsSubscriptions from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-sns-subscriptions';
import { Rule } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-events';
import { LambdaFunction, SnsTopic } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-events-targets';
import path = require('path');
import { ServicePrincipal } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam';

interface PipelineStackProps extends cdk.StackProps {
    websiteBucket: s3.Bucket;
}

export class MyPipelineStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: PipelineStackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        // S3 Bucket for build outputs
        const bucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'PipelineBucket', {
            removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,  
        });

        const copyFilesFunction = new lambda.Function(this, 'CopyFilesFunction', {
            runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
            handler: 'copyWebsiteArtifacts.handler',
            code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, '../lambdas')),
            environment: {
                WEBSITE_BUCKET_NAME: props.websiteBucket.bucketName,
                BUILD_OUTPUT_BUCKET_NAME: bucket.bucketName,
                FOLDER_PATH: 'apps/frontend/dist/'
            },
        });

        props.websiteBucket.grantWrite(copyFilesFunction);
        bucket.grantRead(copyFilesFunction);

        const buildProject = new codebuild.PipelineProject(this, 'PipeProject', {
            environment: { buildImage: codebuild.LinuxBuildImage.STANDARD_5_0 },
            buildSpec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromSourceFilename('buildspec.yml'),
        });

        const sourceOutput = new codepipeline.Artifact();
        const sourceAction = new cpactions.GitHubSourceAction({
            actionName: 'GitHub',
            output: source output,
            oauthToken: cdk.SecretValue.secretsManager(
                'arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-xxxxx-1:xxxxxx:secret:dev/xxxxx/gh-token-1vDO4m'
            ),
            owner: 'owner',
            repo: 'pipes',
            branch: 'master',
        });

        const buildOutput = new codepipeline.Artifact();
        const buildAction = new cpactions.CodeBuildAction({
            actionName: 'CodeBuild',
            project: buildProject,
            input: sourceOutput,
            outputs: [buildOutput],
        });

        const deployAction = new cpactions.S3DeployAction({
            actionName: 'S3Deploy',
            input: buildOutput,
            bucket: bucket,
        });


        const pipeline = new codepipeline.Pipeline(this, 'PipePipeline', {
            pipelineName: 'PipePipeline',
            stages: [
                {
                    stageName: 'Source',
                    actions: [sourceAction],
                },
                {
                    stageName: 'Build',
                    actions: [buildAction],
                },
                {
                    stageName: 'Deploy',
                    actions: [deployAction],
                },
            ],
        });

        const pipelineEvent = new Rule(this, 'PipelineEventRule', {
            eventPattern: {
                source: ['aws.codepipeline'],
                detailType: ['CodePipeline Pipeline Execution State Change'],
                detail: {
                    state: ['SUCCEEDED'],
                    pipeline: [pipeline.pipelineName],
                    stage: ['Deploy']
                }
            }
        });

        copyFilesFunction.addPermission('InvokeByCloudWatch', {
            principal: new ServicePrincipal('events.amazonaws.com')
        });
        pipelineEvent.addTarget(new LambdaFunction(copyFilesFunction));


        // test sns deployment email
        const topic = new sns.Topic(this, 'TestSNSTopic');
        topic.addSubscription(new snsSubscriptions.EmailSubscription('my-email@gmail.com'));
        pipelineEvent.addTarget(new SnsTopic(topic));
    }
}
```

I tried checking CloudTrail, EventBridge, everything seems fine the form of the Rule seems correct and it's enabled, CloudTrail doesn't give me any Events from the Pipeline.

Any advice on how to approach solving/ debugging this? I want to see the Pipeline events that are emitted but I couldn't find them anywhere

Comment: I would literally goto each service in the aws console thats listed in your code (CodeDeploy, CodePipeline, CloudWatch, SNS, Lambda, S3 etc) and look at what state each component of your pipeline/latest build is in - i expect you will see some error. Based on your flow, questions like does the artifact exist or not will help figure out where the flow is broken.

Comment: All the stages are successful, the artifacts are uploaded to the S3, and if I manually trigger the lambda it works as expected. But for some reason, I cannot catch the events from the CodePipeline, I'll try to explore the UI a bit more for the CloudTrail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This event does not have a `stage` prop in it, it is about the entire pipeline.

Here is an example event from the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/detect-state-changes-cloudwatch-events.html#detect-state-events-pipeline-succeeded):

```json
{
    "version": "0",
    "id": "01234567-EXAMPLE",
    "detail-type": "CodePipeline Pipeline Execution State Change",
    "source": "aws.codepipeline",
    "account": "123456789012",
    "time": "2020-01-24T22:03:44Z",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "resources": [
        "arn:aws:codepipeline:us-east-1:123456789012:myPipeline"
    ],
    "detail": {
        "pipeline": "myPipeline",
        "execution-id": "12345678-1234-5678-abcd-12345678abcd",
        "state": "SUCCEEDED",
        "version": 3,
        "pipeline-execution-attempt": 1
    }
}
```

Stage-level events are limited to the following states: `STARTED`, `STOPPING`, `STOPPED` and come with a `CodePipeline Stage Execution State Change` detail-type.

Try a [CodeStar notifucation rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline.Pipeline.html#notifywbronid-target-options):

```js
pipeline.notifyOn(
    "myEvent",
    topic,
    {
        events: [ PipelineNotificationEvents.STAGE_EXECUTION_SUCCEEDED ]
    }
);
```